# Strange behavior of Prismatic Joint of javascript port of Box2D engine

Tags: javascript, box2d, physics, game-physics, physics-engine

Lifting block on prismatic joint (b2PrismaticJointDef) on upper point gives impulse to the dynamic body that lays on lifting block surface even if lifting block doesn't move at all.

Maybe it's bug of javascript port. But I want to fix it because I need of elevators in my game.

## Update v1

I have used **box2dweb** javascript port of Box2DFlash 2.1a https://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/.

## Update v2

Here is similar demo on flash http://hyzhak.github.com/darlingjs/performance/box2dweb/ it has same problems, so maybe this issue on flash or on original Box2D engine.

http://jsfiddle.net/hyzhak/2kjDZ/

```
var b2Vec2 = Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2,
    b2BodyDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2BodyDef,
    b2Body = Box2D.Dynamics.b2Body,
    b2FixtureDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2FixtureDef,
    b2World = Box2D.Dynamics.b2World,
    b2PolygonShape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2PolygonShape,
    b2CircleShape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2CircleShape,          
    b2DebugDraw = Box2D.Dynamics.b2DebugDraw,
    b2PrismaticJointDef = Box2D.Dynamics.Joints.b2PrismaticJointDef;

(function() {    
    var world = buildWorld();

    var leftBlock = buildBlock({world: world, x: 2, y: 8, width: 2, height: 12, static: true});
    var rightBlock = buildBlock({world: world, x: 12, y: 8, width: 2, height: 12, static: true});
    var bottomBlock = buildBlock({world: world, x: 7, y: 13, width: 8, height: 2, static: false});
    var box = buildBlock({world: world, x: 7, y: 10, width: 2, height: 2, static: false});

    var joint = buildPrismaticJoint({world: world, 
                                     anchorA: new b2Vec2(7, 13), 
                                     axis: new b2Vec2(0, 1), 
                                     bodyA: bottomBlock, 
                                     bodyB: world.GetGroundBody()});

    var debugDraw = buildDebugDraw(world);

    setInterval(function(){
        world.Step(1 / 60, 10, 10);
        world.DrawDebugData();
        world.ClearForces();
    },1000/60);
})();

function buildWorld() {    
    return new b2World(
        new b2Vec2(0, 10), //gravity vector
        true
    );
}

function buildBlock(state) {
    var fixDef = new b2FixtureDef;
    fixDef.shape = new b2PolygonShape;
    fixDef.density = 1.0;
    fixDef.friction = 0.5;
    fixDef.restitution = .5;         
    fixDef.shape.SetAsBox(state.width / 2, state.height / 2);
    var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = state.static?b2Body.b2_staticBody:b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(state.x, state.y);
    var body = state.world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
    body.CreateFixture(fixDef);
    return body;
}

//buildPrismaticJoint(world, 9, 15, 0, 1, bottomBlock, world.GetGroundBody());
function buildPrismaticJoint(state) {
    var jointDef = new b2PrismaticJointDef();
    jointDef.Initialize(state.bodyA, state.bodyB, state.anchorA, state.axis);
    jointDef.collideConnected = false;
    jointDef.lowerTranslation = 0.0;
    jointDef.upperTranslation = 5.0;
    jointDef.enableLimit = true;
    jointDef.maxMotorForce = 400.0;
    jointDef.motorSpeed = 3.0;
    jointDef.enableMotor = true;
    return state.world.CreateJoint(jointDef);
}

function buildDebugDraw(world) {
    var debugDraw = new b2DebugDraw();
    debugDraw.SetSprite(document.getElementById("playground").getContext("2d"));
    debugDraw.SetDrawScale(20.0);
    debugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.5);
    debugDraw.SetLineThickness(1.0);
    debugDraw.SetFlags(
        b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit | 
        b2DebugDraw.e_jointBit |
        b2DebugDraw.e_aabbBit |
        b2DebugDraw.e_pairBit |
        b2DebugDraw.e_centerOfMassBit |
        b2DebugDraw.e_controllerBit
    );
    world.SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);

    return debugDraw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using the Box2D v2.2.1 C++ code. I'm using a b2PrismaticJoint between a static body and a moving (dynamic) body to simulate a "lift" (or elevator).

When the lift reaches the upper end of translation along the prismatic joint, it appears to stop. However, when another body is sitting on top of the lift and it reaches the upper end of translation, the body on top the lift begins to "bounce" around as if the lift is still applying a force. (I believe this is exactly what is happening, i.e., the lift's body doesn't translate any further along the prismatic joint, but the prismatic joint's motor is still cranking away and applying upward forces to the body).

I initially resolved this issue by manually setting the prismatic joint's motor speed to 0.0 when the upper end of translation was reached. In my main game loop, i.e., the function that gets called at the frame rate ("tick:" in Box2D or "update:" in Cocos2D), I inserted the following (I'm using Objective-C here and kLiftJointValue is an arbitrary integer constant):

```
// Iterate over all joints (used to prevent upper end oscillations from psimaticJoints on lifts)
for (b2Joint* j = world->GetJointList(); j; j = j->GetNext())
{
    if ((int)(j->GetUserData()) == kLiftJointValue) // check to see if lift is at upper end of translation 
    {
        CGFloat currentTranslation = ((b2PrismaticJoint*)j)->GetJointTranslation();
        CGFloat lowerLimit = ((b2PrismaticJoint*)j)->GetLowerLimit();
        CGFloat upperLimit = ((b2PrismaticJoint*)j)->GetUpperLimit();
        b2Body *bodyA = j->GetBodyA();
        b2Body *bodyB = j->GetBodyB();
        BOOL notStopped = (bodyA->GetType() == b2_dynamicBody || bodyB->GetType() == b2_dynamicBody);

        if (fabsf(currentTranslation - lowerLimit) <= 0.01*(upperLimit - lowerLimit) && notStopped )
        {
            CCLOG(@"Stopping platform");
            (j->GetBodyA())->SetType(b2_staticBody);
            (j->GetBodyB())->SetType(b2_staticBody);
            ((b2PrismaticJoint*)j)->SetMotorSpeed(0.0);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code simply iterates over all joints in the world and looks for those tagged appropriately, and if the body has translated to within 1% of the maximum translation allowed then the moving body is changed to static and the motor is disabled by setting the motor speed to 0. You could also use Box2D collision detection and set the joint's motor speed to 0 that way...

I then realized that the best way to implement this lift (without disturbing anything sitting on top of the lift) was to slowly decelerate the prismatic joint's motor speed gradually. This is how I did it:

```
// Iterate over all joints (used to prevent upper end oscillations from psimaticJoints on lifts)
for (b2Joint* j = world->GetJointList(); j; j = j->GetNext())
{
    if ((int)(j->GetUserData()) == kLiftJointValue) // check to see if lift is at upper end of translation 
    {
        CGFloat currentTranslation = ((b2PrismaticJoint*)j)->GetJointTranslation();
        CGFloat lowerLimit = ((b2PrismaticJoint*)j)->GetLowerLimit();
        CGFloat upperLimit = ((b2PrismaticJoint*)j)->GetUpperLimit();
        b2Body *bodyA = j->GetBodyA();
        b2Body *bodyB = j->GetBodyB();
        BOOL notStopped = (bodyA->GetType() == b2_dynamicBody || bodyB->GetType() == b2_dynamicBody);

        if (fabsf(currentTranslation - lowerLimit) <= 0.25*(upperLimit - lowerLimit) && notStopped)
        {
            // Get current motor speed and update
            CGFloat currentSpeed = ((b2PrismaticJoint*)j)->GetMotorSpeed();
            CGFloat newSpeed;

            if (currentSpeed < 0.0)
            {
                if (fabsf(currentTranslation - lowerLimit) <= 0.01*(upperLimit - lowerLimit) && notStopped )
                {
                    CCLOG(@"Stopping platform");
                    (j->GetBodyA())->SetType(b2_staticBody);
                    (j->GetBodyB())->SetType(b2_staticBody);
                    ((b2PrismaticJoint*)j)->SetMotorSpeed(0.0);
                }
                else
                {
                    CCLOG(@"Decelerating: speed=%f", currentSpeed);
                    newSpeed = 0.95*currentSpeed;
                }
            }
            else if (currentSpeed > 0.0)
            {
                CCLOG(@"Accelerating: speed=%f", currentSpeed);

                newSpeed = 1.05*currentSpeed;

                if (newSpeed > 20.0)
                    newSpeed = 20.0;
            }

            // update motor speed
            ((b2PrismaticJoint*)j)->SetMotorSpeed(newSpeed);
        }            
    }
}
```

You'll need to play with the various constants (especially the constants 0.95 and 1.05) since they are fine-tuned for specific motor properties (maxMotorForce = 1000 and motorSpeed = 20 in my case).

Of course elsewhere in my project I have timers running which reset the lift body and joint motor properties as needed (to make it travel up, then back down by reversing the joint's motor speed with a positive value).

I didn't implement the acceleration/deceleration technique when the lift was translated near the other (bottom) limit since I didn't care about stuff riding the lift being imparted forces in this direction when the lift stopped. However, the same approach as outlined above can be used to smoothly accelerate or decelerate as the lift leaves from or returns to the bottom...